# Book with a half elf protagonist who possessed a mount that he had a friendship with

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember much of this book because I read it nearly a decade ago, but the protagonist was a man.  He was either full elf or half elf. I'm quite certain he possessed a mount that he had a friendship with, and I think there were some dragons or transformation elements. I think it was slightly sexual but not overtly so. It was a free book on an ereader website, some time around 2010? The second book cost money but a chapter or two  was available on the author's website as a demo.  If anyone has heard of this, please let me know.  I know it's a long shot with how little I remember.

Comment: In Roger Zelazny's *Dilvish, the Damned", the protagonist is a human of elven descent who has a talking mount which was transformed from a demonic creature.  It's from 1982, though.